# javascript image preloader

Tags: javascript

I've code a little image pre-loader which looks like it should work but the callback is executed prior to the image being loaded.

```
function imagePreloader(src,callback) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = src;
    image.onLoad = callback()

}

function mainImage(gallery) {
    $('#main_image').attr('src',gallery[itterations])
    imagePreloader(gallery[0],function() {

    $('#main_image').css({opacity:1})
    firstLoad = false;
    itterations ++;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
image.onLoad = callback;
```

instead of

```
image.onLoad = callback()
```

Or you will execute `callback` immediately.

Comment: It doesn't fire at all when I do that.